# cordova build releases 5 apk which to upload

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I am trying to build an android app using cordova 8. As soon as `cordova build android --release` with keystore.

It releases 5 apk file in 5 folder, but I am not sure, which one to upload:-

1. arm64
2. armeabi
3. armv7
4. x86
5. x86_64

Now, I am not sure, which one to release and upload for google play after signing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a plugin containing native libraries? (I'm still using version 6 of Cordova and have only one apk, so either it's new in earlier versions or it's something to do with your project).

The different APKs you're seeing are to support different processors on the devices.

Most devices use armv7 so that's probably the one you want to upload first, but you can upload all the apks to google play.

It you upload only one (ore some) of the APKs, your app will be compatible only with device using corresponding kind of processor.

Comment: I am using cordova 7 and there is no specific thing that can trigger 5 build. Can I upload all version in 1 listing and let google decide the user's device and provide them installable file ?\

Comment: Ok, just found, none of the app is working for any mobile.